# Problems with the Hebrew text in Job 26:12-13?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk, job-iyov-book-of

Proposed correction of the Hebrew text

I know a professor of religious sciences who saw problems with Job 26:12-13 considering it a [hapax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon), especially in the following [verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.26.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> ברוחו שמים שפרה By his wind the heavens were made fair;

He sees a problem with this structure since it escapes the parallelism in which it is inserted, his proposal is to do it like this

> ברוחו שמ ים שפרה

It is based on [Chaim Cohen's work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/089130195X), Biblical [hapax legomena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapax_legomenon) in the light of [Akkadian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkadian_language) and [Ugaritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ugaritic). Claiming that the scribes lost the original meaning of the word שפרה, which originally in the Akkadian language would mean “net” but tradition came to understand it as sweeping or beautified, he also considers שמים wrong because they would be two words that ended up joining over time and coincidentally formed a word, שמ would be by or put and ים would be sea or Yam

So it would look like this

> בכחו רגע הים ובתובנתו מחץ רהב׃ ברוחו שמ ים שפרה חללה ידו נחש בריח׃

With his strength he shook the sea or Yam
And with his dexterity, he harmed Rahab
With his wind he caught Yam or sea in his net
The primeval serpent pierced his hand

Has Judaism seen criticism of this text and how do they respond? Does anyone disagree? This professor knows Hebrew so he seems to be an authority on the subject, you can't say he doesn't understand the issue.

He has published an article about this text but it is in Portuguese, for those who don't know I'm from Brazil, I can insert the article if you want to know more in depth but you will have to know Portuguese or know someone who knows Portuguese.

Comment: *Iyov* is one of the books of Tanach noted for its wealth of hapax legomena, but in this case classical commentators (e.g. Rashi and *Metzudas David*) tend to view "שִׁפְרָה" as meaning that HaShem spread the heavens out as a beautiful canopy, emanating from the ש-פ-ר root (with a sense similar to "וְנָטָה אֶת שַׁפְרִירוֹ" in [*Yirm'yahu* 43:10](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1143.htm#10), describing a canopy).

Comment: Do you mean to say that this professor feels the need to maintain parallelism with the word "ים" in both 26:12 and 26:13? I don't understand why he feels compelled to amend the text on that basis, since you repeatedly see "ים" and "שמים" contrasted in *Iyov* (e.g. [9:8](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2709.htm#8), [11:8-9](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2711.htm#8), [14:11](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2714.htm#11)).

Comment: It rests more on the question of words originally having another meaning. שִׁפְרָה originally according to Chaim Cohen would have a meaning of “net” and not to beautify or sweep and this would fit in the parallelism that surrounds it and the שמ ים that is together in the Masoretic text accidentally the copyist united them and gave in a single word, that is, loss of the original meaning of the word and error when copying another one formulated a loss of meaning in the text in which it was strange to read

Comment: @Shmuel Thanks for editing my question by inserting a link to queries in the content, I'm still learning

Comment: No problem, great to have you learning with us!

Comment: @Thales It seems Chaim Cohen translated שפרה as "a net" (related to the Akkadian "*šaparru*"), and then Naftali Herz Tur-Sinai suggested splitting שמים. But then Tur-Sinai's hypothesis might force him to require that שפרה also be amended to "שִׁפְרָתוֹ" as a noun with a possessive suffix, which is not evident in the text. And even then, Tur-Sinai's new rendering of the verse remains stilted. Seems like a lot of tinkering for no benefit. If anything, it would make more sense to just use Cohen's translation ("By His breath, the heavens are a net") and leave the text alone.

Comment: Ignoring Tur-Sinai's suggestion, Cohen's translation in isolation ("By His breath, the heavens are a net") could sort of parallel other descriptions in Tanach (e.g. [Isaiah 40:22](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1040.htm#22), "הַנּוֹטֶה כַדֹּק שָׁמַיִם"). Regardless, I see no difficulty relating "šaparru" with the classical etymology of שפרה/שפריר (canopies and nets share similarities), and maintaining the translation of the Hebrew as relating to a canopy.

Comment: The issue of parallelism cannot be entirely ignored and the fact that there is a Hapax only reinforces this. And the issue of שמים coincidentally being formed by two words and in a copying work accidentally being transmitted together when in fact they were separated formulates a structure that strengthens the parallelism instead of destroying it. The structure of the text mentions the object Yam, Rahab, Primitive Serpent and the correction inserts the object of the first verse Yam or sea, there seems to be no problem.

Comment: @Thales There is a problem. "With His wind, he placed sea a net" is not the normal way to present a phrase in Hebrew if you're trying to say that "He placed *the* sea *in His* net". And besides that, "שם" would be an awkward verb choice here. As I said, it's stilted.

Comment: @Fred “With his wind he put the sea in his net.”

It is how the teacher translated it in the corrected way.

Comment: I don't understand why a Hapax is a problem that could suggest amending the text.

Comment: @Thales The teacher's translation of the proposed amended version is incorrect, as I mentioned.

Comment: @conceptualinertia It is a problem because there is a break in parallelism. Verses 1, 2 and 4 are correct in their structure and construction, in verse 3 there is a break. So containing a hapax and a word that otherwise would be two but was interconnected a posteriori gives reason to the original understanding of hapax. The corrected form restores the parallelism by inferring that the translators missed the original meaning of hapax and inferring that the scribes may have come to understand שמים not as two words but one, based on what they understood of שפרה

Comment: @conceptualinertia It's not a problem. This effort by Professor Tur Sinai strikes me as an example of the phenomenon in the field of higher criticism (other fields are also not immune to this) where a scholar comes up with some emendation or other notion, falls in love with their own idea, and then becomes blind to its glaring shortcomings. Another example of this: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73933/proverbs-822-31-woman-wisdom-personified-or-actual-being#comment216936_73935

Comment: I will contact this teacher, he has a video on youtube about this text but unfortunately the English translation does not appear. I will expose the arguments presented and wait for a response.

Comment: @Fred It would be very good if you formulate an answer contrary to the one presented so that I can make an outline and present it point by point to the professor who presents this correction.

Comment: @Thales I posted an answer explaining why I think the parallelism works well with the text we have in front of us.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a dikduk expert but by my reading the text in front of us fits well and there's no evidence for changing it.

First, this verse, Job 26:11, is part of a sequence of verses that describes G-d's power and formation of the Earth, the Heavens, and the Water.

So 26:7 describes G-d hanging the earth on nothingness:

> נֹטֶ֣ה צָפ֣וֹן עַל־תֹּ֑הוּ תֹּ֥לֶה אֶ֝֗רֶץ עַל־בְּלִי־מָֽה -- He stretched the North over chaos, he suspended the the Earth on nothingness

[26:8-9](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.26.7-8?lang=bi&lookup=Who%20suspended%20earth%20over%20emptiness.%20%D7%A6%D6%B9%D7%A8%D6%B5%D6%BD%D7%A8%D6%BE%D7%9E%D6%B7%D6%A5%D7%99%D6%B4%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D6%BC%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%91%D6%B8%D6%91%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%95%D6%B0%D7%9C%D6%B9%D6%BD%D7%90%D6%BE%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%91%D6%B0%D7%A7%D6%B7%D6%96%D7%A2%20%D7%A2%D6%B8%D7%A0%D6%B8%D6%A3%D7%9F%20%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%97%D6%B0%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B8%D6%BD%D7%9D%D7%83%20He%20wrapped%20up%20the%20waters%20in%20His%20clouds%3BYet%20no%20cloud%20burst%20under%20their%20weight.&with=Commentary&lang2=he) then move on to the heavens (both physical and spiritual) describing G-d's creation of clouds and his hiding of the heavenly Throne.

The four verses 26:10-13, then go back and forth discussing G-d's guidance and power over the seas and the heavens.

26:10 discusses G-ds control of the seas on Earth through the boundary between water and land and light (above the water surface) and darkness (below the water surface).

26:11 discusses G-d's power as it relates to the heavens.

26:12 turns back to the seas this time emphasizing G-d's power over the sea.

Finally, in 26:13, Job describes G-d's use of the wind to control or create beautiful boundary for the heavens (*see* [Ibn Ezra ad loc](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.26.13?lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Job.26.13.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en).) The reference to the escaping serpent is relevant to both the heavens and the waters as explained by the [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.26.13?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en) on this verse.

In summation, the verses in Job 26:10-13 go back and forth multiple times between heaven (aka, the upper waters in Genesis 1) and seas of Earth (aka, the lower waters). The opening and closing verses focus more on G-d's guidance and control. The two middle verses focus on G-d's power.

שפרה in turn is not really a Hapax Legemon, but rather a variation on known words, as explained by Rashi and Ibn Ezra on the spot.

Comment: You are forgetting that the structure of the text deals with cosmogonic objects, Yam, Rahab, primeval serpent. Referring to mythologies of the Levant, or what would Rahab be? The prostitute who helped in the conquest of Canaan? Or pride and insolence? So correlating with God's creations or his divine aspect doesn't seem to make sense. However, verse 3 deviates from the pattern of what was being presented before and after, it has no cohesion, while reinterpreting שפרה and admitting that there was a failure in the transmission of שמ ים can elucidate and thus give cohesion to the parallelism.

Comment: @Thales I think you are presuming meaning that is not all obvious. Clouds and water are not cosmogonic objects. The Jewish commentaries have various explanations on what Rahab and the Serpent are without interpreting them as cosmogonic. But regardless, the parallel still works. Sea, Heaven, Sea, Heaven.  The last Sea compares his power over the sea with his power over Rahab. And the last Heaven compares his power over heaven with his power over the Nachash.

Comment: @Thales In your professor's version the verses go Sea, Heaven, Sea, Sea. That just doesn't fit well. Either group all of the sea verses together or alternate consistently.  According to your position, it is awkward.  I'm also not sure how you are translating רגע הים (quieting or stilling the sea). Why do you think that parallel with מָ֣חַץ רָֽהַב works better than 26:13?

Comment: The 4 objects refer to cosmological beings, Yam in the mythology of the Levant represents the indomitable sea, chaos. Rahab represents a kind of sea monster, then we have the untamed sea again and at the end a monster, of course I am leaning towards those who claim that Job was influenced by the surrounding myths. Heaven in their midst as it is in the Masoretic text is not standard.

Comment: The whole matter boils down to the interpretation of שפרה as suggesting something like netting rather than beautifying. If it is a network, the word connected heaven makes no sense, but separating שמים into שמ ים would improve and fit the parallelism.

Comment: @Thales 1) In your version, why is Yam mentioned twice but the other two are only mentioned once. 2) הַיָּ֑ם is The sea, not a proper name, Yam.  3) In which texts is heaven not in the middle of the sea discussion?
It seems to me that you are proposing a different parallelism but not really explaining why mine is invalid and acknowledging that mine fits the Masoretic text better.  So if we have a valid parallelism with the text before us, why would we change the text to fit some other theoretical parallelism?

Comment: There is also something that is being overlooked. The terms used in parallelism are aggressive terms. Stilled , struck and pierced, verse 3 mentions calmed in Sefaria or beautiful in current and acclaimed translations, i.e. it is taken out of context. The structure was of something being attacked, as there is mention of a cosmogonic being, Rahab, who is found in surrounding myths, so the primeval serpent and Yam might suggest the same.

Comment: @Thales I should point out, incidentally, the word רהב here (r-h-b) is not spelled the same as the character Raḥab (רחב, r-ḥ-b) from the Book of Joshua. It's not even clear that the word the word רהב used in Job is even a proper noun (cf., for instance, Psalms 90:10), though both the term רהב as well as the נחש בריח (what you called the "primeval serpent") are terms that are sometimes understood in Tanach as figurative references to Egypt. This is one reason why it's so important to be able to analyze the text in the original Hebrew without having to imbibe interpretations through a filter.

Comment: @Fred Did I just mention that some explanation conceptualinertia had to come up with of Rahab, if it wasn't a sea monster what was it? The prostitute couldn't be, neither could pride. Your explanation of it being symbolic of Egypt has merit but if Job is said to predate the Exodus then how does that fit in?

Comment: @Thales Egypt existed as an entity both before and after the Exodus. || My point about r-h-b versus r-ḥ-b is that it's easy to confuse words like that if you are relying on English translations. I bring that up to more broadly illustrate a hazard inherent in studying the Bible w/o the requisite grounding in Biblical Hebrew. It's important to be able to study the original Hebrew text in order to be capable of properly scrutinizing translations and academic hypotheses. In this particular case, it's much easier to undermine Tur-Sinai's emendation of the passage in Job if you understand Hebrew.

Comment: The passage, if it refers to Egypt, portrays God hurting him, that is, it is something after the Exodus and the book is said to portray a theme before him. I did not correlate Rahab in Job with the prostitute in Joshua, I just provoked conceptual inertia to define what Rahab would be in Job. Does that mean, then, that Tur-Sinai knew nothing of Hebrew?

Comment: @Thales Of course Tur-Sinai knew Hebrew, but that doesn't mean he was right. It's much easier for third parties to properly evaluate his proposal if *they* understand Hebrew. Paul of Tarsus understood Hebrew well, but he spewed all sorts of egregious distortions of Bible verses when speaking to the Galatians, who did not understand Hebrew and were therefore incapable of evaluating his claims. I'm not saying that Tur-Sinai was being deliberately dishonest, but it's important to know Hebrew to evaluate his arguments.

Answer (score 1):

[Conceptual Inertia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11567/conceptualinertia) posted a good [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/132155) on parallelism and hapax legomena. But just to add a couple of points:

Dr. [Chaim Cohen](https://www.laniertheologicallibrary.org/chaim-cohen-collection/) (*Biblical Hapax Legomena in the Light of Akkadian and Ugaritic*, 1978) observed that the Hebrew "שפרה" is a possible cognate of the Akkadian "[*šaparru*](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian/dosearch.php?searchkey=saparru&language=rawakkadian)" (meaning "net"). However, this does not imply that the two words share the same meaning. Often, the definitions of cognates diverge in their respective languages, including Semitic languages as closely related as Hebrew, Akkadian, and Ugaritic.

As Rashi<sup>1</sup> and the *Metzudas David* observe in their commentaries on [Job 26:13](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%92), "שִׁפְרָה" bears a similarity with the Hebrew word "שפריר" (a noun meaning "canopy", *cf.* Jeremiah 43:10, "וְנָטָה אֶת שַׁפְרִירוֹ") and may be a [*pi'el*](https://uhg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stem_piel.html) conjugation ("He canopied the heavens"). There's a degree of similarity in meaning between "canopy" and "net" that is consistent with what you'd expect of Semitic cognates.

It seems Cohen disregarded this and chose to simply apply the precise Akkadian translation of "*šaparru*" directly to the Hebrew in
Job 26:13. Professor [Naftali Herz Tur-Sinai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Herz_Tur-Sinai) took this further and suggested splitting שמים into two words (שָׂם יָם), which he felt would make the verse more consistent with Cohen's translation:

> ברוחו שם ים שפרה

Which Prof. Tur-Sinai interprets to mean:

> With His wind, He caught the sea in His net

There are a number of problems with this, however. First of all, this emendation appears highly speculative. It is ostensibly motivated to by a preference for associating a net with the sea rather than the heavens (which presupposes that Cohen's translation of "net" is compelling, which it is not), as well as a desire to impose a polytheistic Levantine mythological milieu onto Job.

Secondly, Tur-Sinai's hypothesis would require that שפרה also be emended to "בְּשִׁפְרָתוֹ" as a noun with a prepositional prefix and possessive suffix. None of this is indicated in the text.

Thirdly, Akkadian has [many different words for "net"](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian/dosearch.php?searchkey=net&language=english&offset=0), and "[*šaparru*](http://www.assyrianlanguages.org/akkadian/dosearch.php?searchkey=1107&language=id)" carries the sense of a net used for transporting something over land rather than for catching something or for use in the water.

Incidentally, Tur-Sinai's use of the past participle "שָׂם" ("placed" or "put") seems a bit unusual in this context. In Biblical Hebrew, when "שָׂם" or other conjugations of its root operate on large features of geography or nature (the land, the sea, the sky, countries, cities, etc.), and specifically when those features are the direct object of an independent clause, they typically mean "made" or "transformed" rather than "placed" or "put" (*e.g.*, "Who made [שָׂם] the whole world?" Job 34:13, where "world" is the direct object<sup>2</sup>).

By contrast, when describing the Almighty's physical movement of these large features of geography, the verses tend to employ a variegated assortment of different verbs, some of which appear in this very chapter (26) of Job ("נֹטֶה צָפוֹן", "תֹּלֶה אֶרֶץ", "רָגַע הַיָּם") and elsewhere ("הַמַּעְתִּיק הָרִים" in 9:5, "הַמַּרְגִּיז אֶרֶץ מִמְּקוֹמָהּ" in 9:6, "נֹטֶה שָׁמַיִם" in 9:8, as well as other conjugations of נתן, שלח, רקע, etc.). If Job 26:13 is indeed describing placing the sea into a net, one might have expected some such verb to appear. Alas, it does not.

Finally, the word "שָׁמַיִם" ("heavens") that appears in the Masoretic text of Job 26:13 also shows up hundreds of times throughout the Bible. On the other hand, there are **zero** Biblical appearances of word pair ("שם ים") with which Tur-Sinai wishes to replace it. This itself renders Tur-Sinai's emendation improbable.

Professor Tur-Sinai's approach to this verse seems to require a lot of unnecessary tinkering. Even if one insists on using Cohen's speculative translation of "שפרה" as "net", it would be far less linguistically problematic to just use it as is ("With His wind, the heavens are a net"<sup>3</sup>) and leave the text alone.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that Rashi (on Job 26:12 and Isaiah 27:1) identifies both "רָהַב" and "נָחָשׁ בָּרִחַ" as allegorical references to Egypt, the former based on the identification provided by Isaiah 30:7 ("וּמִצְרַיִם הֶבֶל וָרִיק יַעְזֹרוּ לָכֵן קָרָאתִי לָזֹאת רַהַב הֵם שָׁבֶת")</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>As opposed to where the large geographical feature is the indirect object, as in Psalms 89:26, where the meaning is "placed"</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>*Cf.* Isaiah 40:22, "הַנּוֹטֶה כַדֹּק שָׁמַיִם"</sub>

Comment: In the professor's article in question, there is the opposite, it was Tsu-Sinai and not Cohen who first suggested that שפרה means network, Cohen refines Tsu-Sinai's understanding by suggesting that there was a slip by the copyist later, losing the original understanding of שפרה ended up uniting what before would be two words שם ים, making the meaning of the verse something totally new. I will present your text to the professor and wait if he is convinced or bring his counterarguments.

Comment: @Thales Perhaps I got the Cohen and Tur-Sinai's positions mixed up. I don't have direct access to their writings, and was relying on a combination of what you wrote about their positions and what I found on [this site](https://benhateva.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/29231/). Anyway, I just added something to the answer about different Akkadian words for "net".

Comment: @Thales Has the professor responded?

Comment: Reply did but as the references you gave are primarily from religious authorities like Rashi he didn't feel compelled to respond objectively, he just said he agrees with Cohen's conclusions. I consider him a professor who is very closed in his conclusions, especially when the counter-argument is based on religious literature, kind of wanting to be refuted by others like him.

Comment: @Thales That's weird. I cited Rashi and another commentary once, and it was not critical to my thesis. I marshaled many arguments based on direct analysis of the text, logic, and the actual connotation of the proposed Akkadian cognate. None of which were dependent on "religious authorities." But one mention of "Rashi and the *Metzudas David*" was enough of a pretext to allow your professor to ignore all my points and continue blindly along the primrose path forged by a different group of authorities. How ironic.

Comment: @Thales I should add that I didn't write up this post to provoke some kind of disputation with your professor, but rather I wrote it for the readership of Mi Yodeya and yourself. You were the one who wanted to submit it to your professor for review, to which I had no objection.